# How to get rid of the white frame around the window? Gnome-screenshot

Tags: gnome

I am currently using the `gnome-screenshot` application. I have tried to edit dconf settings under org>gnome>gnome-screenshot and have tried to edit the window-frame option without success. I have the same problem when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that there is a white border around your screenshots.

The gray and white checkered pattern you are seeing indicates *transparency* (see-through)

The windows on your desktop have *semi-transparent* shadows around them. These shadows are captured when you take a screenshot of the window.  If you were to post the images on a black or colored background, there will not be a white border.

Note that the screenshot of the screenshot you uploaded here does not have the checkered pattern, but has a shadow when posted here on AskUbuntu where the default background color is white.